# How could the T-1000 use time travel technology?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

It is established in The Terminator that anything travelling through time needs to be encased in living tissue. However, the T-1000 just seems to be made of liquid metal. Does the movie ever address this, or is it just a giant plot hole?